# loop with array values

Tags: php, arrays, loops

i have this array:

```
$um = array("PHP", "Python", "Java", "C++");
```

and i need something like this:

```
PHP ------- Python
PHP ------- Java
PHP ------- C++
Python ---- Java
Python ---- C++
Java ------ C++
```

so, i am trying:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($um); $i++) {
    for ($x = 1; $x < count($um); $x++) {
        echo $um[$i]."-----".$um[$x]."\n";
    }
}
```

but i get this output

```
PHP------Python
PHP------Java
PHP------C++
Python---Python
Python---Java
Python---C++
Java-----Python
Java-----Java
Java-----C++
C++------Python
C++------Java
C++------C++
```

Any idea how can i correct the loop ?

Comment: I wonder how you could get that far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value that $x is set to in your inner for loop from $x = 1 to $x = $i + 1

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($um); $i++) {
    for ($x = $i + 1; $x < count($um); $x++) {
        echo $um[$i]."-----".$um[$x]."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($um); $i++) {
    for ($x = $i + 1; $x < count($um); $x++) {
        echo $um[$i]."-----".$um[$x]."\n";
    }
}
```

The error is that you have to change the

```
$x = 1;
```

with this one:

```
$x = $i + 1;
```